# Oracle APEX_MAIL send to multiple recipients

Tags: oracle, email, oracle-apex

What is the syntax for sending emails to multiple recipients with APEX_MAIL.SEND?

The official page, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_mail.htm#AEAPI342, says; *p_to
Valid email address to which the email will be sent (required). For multiple email addresses, use a comma-separated list* However doesn't show an example of the syntax.

Using the example they give does anyone know the syntax?

```
DECLARE
    l_body      CLOB;
BEGIN
l_body := 'Thank you for your interest in the APEX_MAIL 
package.'||utl_tcp.crlf||utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body ||'  Sincerely,'||utl_tcp.crlf;
l_body := l_body ||'  The APEX Dev Team'||utl_tcp.crlf;
apex_mail.send(
    p_to       => 'some_user@somewhere.com',   -- change to your email address
    p_from     => 'some_sender@somewhere.com', -- change to a real senders email address
    p_body     => l_body,
    p_subj     => 'APEX_MAIL Package - Plain Text message');
END;
```

/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to put multiple comma separated mail addresses into the p_to parameter.
See this example:

```
DECLARE
  l_body      CLOB;
BEGIN
  l_body := 'Thank you for your interest in the APEX_MAIL package.'||utl_tcp.crlf||utl_tcp.crlf;
  l_body := l_body ||'  Sincerely,'||utl_tcp.crlf;
  l_body := l_body ||'  The APEX Dev Team'||utl_tcp.crlf;
  apex_mail.send(
    p_to       => 'some_user@somewhere.com,other_user@elsewhere.com',   -- separate multiple recipients with comma
    p_from     => 'some_sender@somewhere.com', -- change to a real senders email address
    p_body     => l_body,
    p_subj     => 'APEX_MAIL Package - Plain Text message');
END;
```

hth, Moritz

Comment: Thanks, I did try this before but another error in my code made it seem like it wasn't working.